# Are Google Forms meant to be "writable" AND the results also "readable" from a website

Tags: google-forms

Overall, I'm looking to create a website where the user needs to pass a little quiz to see each additional level of content (and ought never have to quiz again for each higher level).  He/she will see the first level of content without any kind of registration.

Google Forms can handle registration, but is this information then readable to a website, and how (or does that not work)?  Google forms can of course handle quiz questions, but then how would the results of the user passing be read by the website to determine display, or is Google Forms simply not designed for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) could be used to create and edit forms and to send and read responses. The specific service is the [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) but if send responses to a Google Sheet you could read the responses from there.

Note: Be aware that the responses sent to a Google Sheet are not synced back with the Google Form, in other words, if you change a value o a Google Sheet the original value is kept unchanged on the Google Form.